# Grails - Make searches with different fields

Tags: grails, plugins, searchable

I'm using Grails 2.3.x and the Searchable plugin,

Imagine the next domain class book (String Author, String Title, Date pubDate);

I need to make a search with different fields, for example;

I want to search the books with a publication date (pubDate) between `Field1: 03/03/2014` and `Field2: 04/04/2014`,
also for example: the books with the title X and pubDate between `Field1: 03/03/2014` and `Field2: 04/04/2014`

Is anyway to do a search with different parameters with the searchable plugin?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
Where do I need to write that code?
`def search = {`
`...`
        `Book.search {`
                       `gt("pubDate", field1)` 
                     `lt("pubDate", field2)`
                    `}`
    `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searchable provides a search builder that should accomplish this. You can do your searches like this:

```
Book.search {
    gt("pubDate", field1)
    lt("pubDate", field2)
}
```

and

```
Book.search {
    term("title", x)
    gt("pubDate", field1)
    lt("pubDate", field2)
}
```

That code will search the index for all `Book` objects that meet the criteria and return a `List` those `Book`s. You can put that in your controller or in a service. For instance, here is what it would look like in a controller action:

```
def searchBooks(String title, Date pubDate) {
    def books = Book.search(result: 'every') {
        term('title', title)
        gt('pubDate', pubDate)    
    }

    render view: 'list', [bookList: books]
}
```

See this doc: http://grails.org/Searchable+Plugin+-+Searching+-+Query+Builder

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand something; where do I need to write that code? Within the search method that I copied in my BookController?